# Excel Not Selecting All Rows

Tags: excel, excel-2007, ms-office, excel-2010

When I click CTRL+A in Excel 2007 to copy all of my 1000 rows
I notice that excel does some kind of automatic grouping and selects for example 15 rows as only one row.
When I paste the rows only 300 of 1000 are pasted.

How can I select all rows without automatic grouping?

Comment: Try clicking the corner where columns and rows meet, this will select your worksheet (not sure if that's possible or works for you).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - my mistake - I forgot to include all the values in the filter. :)